# Finding velocity from distance and gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, velocity, projectile

Basically, I have a problem that asks:

> An object is launched to a height of 2 miles, what was it's initial speed and time.

Now normally something like this would be fairly basic. The problem though is that velocity, acceleration, and time are not given. I can see that gravity would most likely be used in finding the initial velocity. But I have not been able to find how to do so. What would be used to find these?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably assume that you can neglect air friction and that the acceleration due to gravity a constant -9.8 m/s^2. Also, from the wording of the question, it sounds like you can assume that the maximum height reached was 2 miles. Using your intuition, do you see how all this information results in a unique trajectory? Write down the general equation for the trajectory of a projectile and put in the constraint condition that it reaches a maximum height of 2 miles. You should be able to work out the initial speed as well as the time it took to go from its initial position to the maximum height of 2 miles.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the equation $v^2 = v_0^2 + 2gd$.  If you're referring to the 2 mile point as being the apex of the path then you know the value of v, i.e. the final velocity, and you're given d so you should be able to solve for the initial velocity, $v_0$.  (Be sure that the value you use for the height has units consistent with the units you use for g.)

Alternatively, you can  think of this in terms of the energy of the system:  the change in potential energy is equal to the change in kinetic energy.  You'll get the same result either way.

Once you have that value, you can use the equation $s = (1/2)gt^2 + v_0 t$ to solve for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 3rd equation of motion v(square)=u(square)+2*a*s.v is zero, u you are finding ,a is acc. due to gravitation and it is 9.8 m/s(square), s is displacement or height which is 2 mile you will have to change it to the appropriate unit.That would do for initial speed,then use the equation v = u + at and you will have your answer